# Upload a file and json data in django restframework

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm uploading a file and along with it I've few data fields to parse
[json in restapi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1s7o.png)

views.py

```
class FileView(APIView):
    def get(self,request):
        #request.content_type= 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryyrV7KO0BoCBuDbTL'
        content = r'Submit File.'
        return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        try:
            print(request.content_type)
            print(request.data)
            parser_classes =(MultiPartParser, JSONParser)
            if not request.data.get('filename'):
                content = "File is not uploaded !! Please upload a sample"
                return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

            file = request.data.get('filename')
            print(file)
            request_Details = { }
            request_Details['creator'] = request.data.get("creator", None)
            request_Details['enable'] = request.data.get('enable', None)
            request_Details['type'] = request.data.get('type', None)
            request_Details['filename']  = request.data.get('filename')
            requestsData = requests(filename=request_Details['filename'],creator=request_Details['creator'],enable=request_Details['enable'],type=request_Details['type'],)
            requestsData.save()
            content = "File submitted successfully"
            return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        except Exception as exp:
            logger.error("Exception in submitRequestView POST function ", exc_info=True)
            content = {'Exception': 'Internal Error'}
            return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

model.py

```
class requests(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    creator = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    enable = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    filename = models.FileField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

serializer.py

```
class RequestsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.requests
        fields = ('filename', 'creator', 'type', 'enable',)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    #url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^File_upload/', views.FileView.as_view()),

]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

setting.py(I've attached the media path code only)

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media') 

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'#
```

My json request is as follows

```
{
"filename":"C://Users//Administrator//Desktop//file1.zip",
"creator":"aarav",
"enable":"yes",
"type":"dll"
}
```

and making use of media type as multipart/form-data not application/json , and MultipartParser and JsonParser classes in views.py.
I've tested my code from postman and I'm able to upload image to media folder and store the filename and other details in database.
Now when I try to POST from django restapi as shown in image attached , and I get the below error

```
Module : File_upload  ERROR Exception in submitRequestView POST function
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\fileupload\restapi_file\views.py", line 464, in post
    print(request.data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\request.py", line 212, in data
    self._load_data_and_files()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\request.py", line 275, in _load_data_and_files
    self._data, self._files = self._parse()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\request.py", line 350, in _parse
    parsed = parser.parse(stream, media_type, self.parser_context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\parsers.py", line 116, in parse
    raise ParseError('Multipart form parse error - %s' % six.text_type(exc))
ParseError: Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None
```

How to solve this and post request using restframework and not use any templates..??

Comment: In order to help answer your question, you should really include the relevant Python code that you are having an issue with.  The stack trace you posted is not all that useful without seeing the code that it raises the error on.

Comment: edited the question and views.py,model.py,serializer.py,urls.py,setting.py

Comment: This code works well when tested in postman , but coming to restapi, I'm giving content as json meentioned above, what might be the issue and I feel really stuck at this from long ago